# How do you read a lambda function as a string?

Tags: python, string, function, lambda

I'd like to read a lambda function I created as a string, after I created it.

For example,

```
func = lambda num1,num2: num1 + num2
```

I'd like to read func as:

```
'lambda num1,num2: num1 + num2'
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or even read any part of the lambda function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit**: Changed my first answer as I misunderstood the question. This answer is borrowed from a number of other uses, however I have completed the code to only display the part of the string that you want.

```
import inspect

func = lambda num1,num2: num1 + num2
funcString = str(inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0])
funcString = funcString.strip("['\\n']").split(" = ")[1]
print funcString
```

Outputs the following string:

```
lambda num1,num2: num1 + num2
```

Comment: If I copy and paste the code above I get an error at line 3:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 1006, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 835, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. @Siderius try running the code from a file instead of an interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`getsourcelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) from  the `inspect` module to do this

This function returns as a list all of the lines of the definition of any function, module, class or method as well as the line number at which it was defined.

For example:

```
import inspect

f = lambda x, y : x + y

print inspect.getsourcelines(f)[0][0]
```

Will output the definition of the function as:

```
f = lambda x, y: x + y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python's [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to get the desired code as a list of strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import inspect

func = lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2

def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a + b

def get_code_as_string(passed_func):
    return inspect.getsourcelines(passed_func)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # feed a lambda function
    print(get_code_as_string(func))

    # feed a normal function
    print(get_code_as_string(f))
```

The output is as follows:

```
(['func = lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2\n'], 6)
(['def f():\n', '    a = 1\n', '    b = 2\n', '    return a + b\n'], 8)
```

As you can see `inspect.getsourcelines()` returns a tuple of a list and an integer. The list contains all the lines of the function passed to `inspect.getsourcelines()` and the integer represents the line number in which the provided functions starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `eval()` function:

```
>>> func = eval('lambda num1,num2: num1 + num2')
>>> func
<function <lambda> at 0x7fe87b74b668>
```

To evaluate any expression and return the value.

Comment: eval is evil and considered bad practice... advise against it.

Comment: Also this is the opposite of the desired solution, OP is looking to get the string from the lambda, not create the lambda from the string.