# How can I get exactly the code of a lambda function in python?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I would like to know if there is a way to get the code of the following lambda functions:

```
a = {"test": lambda x: x + 123, "test2": lambda x: x + 89}
```

Is there a way to like

```
print(getsource(a["test"])
```

That returns :

```
lambda x: x + 123
```

I'm already aware of inspect and dill getsource functions but the following code:

```
import inspect
import dill

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = {"test": lambda x: x + 123, "test2": lambda x: x + 89}

    print(inspect.getsource(a["test"]))
    print(dill.source.getsource(a["test"]))
```

Returns:

```
a = {"test": lambda x: x + 123, "test2": lambda x: x + 89}

a = {"test": lambda x: x + 123, "test2": lambda x: x + 89}
```

Comment: Doesn't `a["test"]` give you the code of the `lambda` function?

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response, unfortunately no, I only get : <function <lambda> at 0x000000000204C1E0>

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? `lambda x: x +123` as a string?

Comment: Yes, I would like to print the lambda function definition as a string.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30984012/8268531

Comment: No because this answer manipulates the line returned by inspect.getsourcelined. For my problem, the line returned by this method is the same for both lambda functions. I could use this kind of trick to get the start of the lambda function but I think that it would be impossible to stop at the right place in the string to get the exact definition.

Comment: Possible solution is to create one lambda function per line of code. Another option is to use `ast` module together with appropriate parser like `astunparse` project to analyze and modify source code. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified-source-c

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem so I wrote a few code that I believe can at least partially address this.

```
def get_lambda_source(lambda_func, position):
    import inspect
    import ast
    import astunparse
    code_string = inspect.getsource(lambda_func).lstrip()
    class LambdaGetter(ast.NodeTransformer):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.lambda_sources = []

        def visit_Lambda(self, node):
            self.lambda_sources.append(astunparse.unparse(node).strip()[1:-1])

        def get(self, code_string):
            tree = ast.parse(code_string)
            self.visit(tree)
            return self.lambda_sources
    return LambdaGetter().get(code_string)[position]
```

In your case,

```
print(get_lambda_source(a['test'], 0]))
```

returns

```
lambda x: x + 123
```

Note this doesn't work in the shell.

Comment: **Brilliant.** This is foolproof, which is nice. But this also requires the third-party `astunparse` package *and* is hideously slow, which is less than nice. [A comparable solution in the third-party `icontract` package behaves similarly but substitutes `astunparse` with `asttokens`](https://github.com/Parquery/icontract/blob/6fb85fe00e91a0b27369a543642d071feb7740d6/icontract/represent.py#L157). It's pick your poison either way, of course. `</sigh>`

Answer (score 1):

How about the following function `mygetsource`?

```
import inspect

def mygetsource(l, n):
    s = inspect.getsource(l[n])
    s = s[s.index('{')+1:-2]
    d = {x[1:x.index(':')-1]: x[x.index(':')+2:] for x in s.split(', ')}
    return d[n]

a = {"test": lambda x: x + 123, "test2": lambda x: x + 89}
print(mygetsource(a, "test"))
print(mygetsource(a, "test2"))
b = {'func1': lambda y: y * 10, 'func2': lambda z: z ** z}
print(mygetsource(b, "func1"))
print(mygetsource(b, 'func2'))
```

Below is the result:

```
lambda x: x + 123
lambda x: x + 89
lambda y: y * 10
lambda z: z ** z
```